# Plug-in crashed: "file-png.exe" in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I attempted to add several png files to my project's.xcf file in GIMP 2.10.22 and received this error.

> Plug-in crashed: "file-png.exe" (D:\Softwears\Gimp\GIMP
> 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\file-png\file-png.exe)
>
> The dying plug-in may have messed up GIMP's internal state. You may
> want to save your images and restart GIMP to be on the safe side.

I then restarted the application, but it still didn't function.And then I just reinstalled the latest issue (2.10.30) version as well.This is the stable release, and I launched the software, made a new file without altering anything, and attempted to import several other.png files, but I received the same issue.

Given below is the error I get, And the blurred part is just the path of the image file.
[image: This is the error I get. And the blurred part is just the path of the image file.]

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Gimp's `Edit > Preferences > System resources > Resource consumption > Tile cache size`. This is the maximum RAM Gimp will use to store the image pixels (layers, channel, so most of the RAM Gimp uses). When it needs more than this it starts its own swapping to disk (the swap file is created in the `Swap folder` as defined in `Preferences > Folders`).

[image: Tile cache]

[image: Swap folder location]

IIRC initially this is defined to be half the RAM available, but if you have many apps running, including a few big ones, this may be too much, so you can set it to something smaller (your available RAM when Gimp isn't running). Of course when Gimp starts swapping to disk performance suffers considerably.